# How to determine the sequencing of event execution in a SystemC simulation

Tags: systemc

As an example, say my code has three functions which are all sensitive to positive edge of the same clock. Is there a way to tell how a given SystemC simulator sequences the execution of these functions?

I am using Cadence's IUS simulator.

I understand that the code should not assume the sequencing as it is modeling hardware. But I am asking this question because knowing the sequencing of events is critical to facilitate SystemC debugging.

Answer (score 1):

No, for processes sensitive to same event, SystemC standard does not guarantee some specific execution sequence.
You should use channels for inter-process communication, so behavior of your simulation would not depend on exact execution sequence.

Internally, handles of all processes that are sensitive to same event will be stored inside event object. So when event is triggered, sequence of proccess execution is predefined (by order in which handles are stored inside event). This information is private however, so you can't use it in application code:

```
class sc_event {
...
private:
    ...

    mutable std::vector<sc_method_handle> m_methods_static;
    mutable std::vector<sc_method_handle> m_methods_dynamic;
    mutable std::vector<sc_thread_handle> m_threads_static;
    mutable std::vector<sc_thread_handle> m_threads_dynamic;
}
```

Comment: Yes, SystemC standard does not guarantee a specific sequence. But is there a way to determine the actual sequence, after compilation, perhaps. This is strictly for debugging purpose. My systemC simulation is crashing, and I am dealing with +100k lines of code. I am trying to get the event sequencing info to guide where I should put breakpoints.

Comment: I've modified my answer.  Technically you can modify SystemC source code to make this information public or by creating a friend function. You can check sc_event::trigger() method to get order of methods/threads execution.